# Custom UIButton background image showing in iOS 6 but not iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uibutton, ios6

I set the button background in the interface builder, but that wasn't showing up so I set it programmatically. All (but one button... why?) shows on the simulator but never show on a device.

I get this output:

`Could not load the "gray_button.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.ios"`

This is the code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.getMyTripButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                                          [[self getFullPathname] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images/gray_button.png"]]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.popupButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                                      [[self getFullPathname] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images/gray_button.png"]]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [self.viewOurPackages reloadData];
}
```

I have also tried replacing `imageWithContentsOfFile` with `imageNamed` and both yield the same results.

I have added the images directory in my Project > Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, but I think this is where it all starts to go wrong and I can't figure out why.  Possibly because it's a directory?

*I would like to point out that I have double and triple checked that it is not a capitalization/case-sensitive issue.*

**UPDATE: I have solved the one button not showing. It would seem that real issue is that the images show on iOS6 and NOT on iOS5.**

Comment: If it is showing in simulator and not in device, possible issue is that the file name is wrong. Check gray_button.png is exactly is same and there are no capital letters used anywhere else. In simulator it works fine, but in device it wont work if name is different.

Comment: That is the right name, but I will say we do have a gray_button.png and a gray_button@2x.png

Comment: Try cleaning & rebuilding your project in both simulator & device and check the results if anything changes.

Comment: This has been a problem for a month but I put it on the back burner because actual implementation needed attention. I have cleaned & rebuilt the project numerous times in that span.

Comment: Try it in viewDidAppear.  It probably is because your buttons were not ready.

Comment: I had it in `viewDidAppear` and then I read another SO question that said normally it's done in `viewWillAppear`. Only this class has it in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was one (or a combination) of the following 3 things:

1. Make sure your image file is formatted correctly. Sometimes png files need a little coercing. (I think this specifically was my problem)
2. Make sure your button is of type Custom in the Interface Builder or `UIButtonTypeCustom`.
3. If you are setting the image in Interface Builder and it's still not showing, set it explicitly in the code using `[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]` (or `[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]` depending on which one you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding a folder to the copy bundles, then instead of referencing the file as `gray_button.png`, you should reference if from code or xib You will have to include the directory in the name too such as `directory/gray_button.png`

Comment: I do that. I get the full pathname. I have also tried it with just `images/gray_button.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Steph,

If you used `@synthesize` for the button in the `.h file`, then getters and setters are automatically created. Thus (this is a longshot and just a thought) having the name `getMyTripButton` could be confusing Xcode somehow. Try renaming the variable?

As far as the image not loading... for one of the buttons and not the other... da faq? Is this the only places that `gray_button.png` is getting called? (for example, you aren't modifying that button somewhere else that may tell it to use that image again). Have you tried putting it in the same directory as the nib that is using it? are you sure `getMyTripButton` is properly tied from the nib to the code?

Last thing I can think of for now:
you said

> I set the button background in the interface builder, but that wasn't
>   showing up so I set it programmatically. All (but one button... why?)
>   shows on the simulator but never show on a device

do you have `popupButton`'s background image also set in the nib/interface builder? if you already have it set there and are setting it again here, it may be that it isn't really getting set in the code at all and is just using what is in interface builder which could explain why `getMyTripButton` may not be showing up/showing the background image.

If I think of anything else that could be causing the issue i'll edit this post. Good luck, and hang in there.